# How to make a HIGH pin on ESP8266 go LOW when device is turned off using a low side switch?

Tags: esp8266, low-side

I ran into this issue while working with WeMos D1 Mini and Adafruit's [timer board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3435).

I had an N-channel MOSFET that was driven by the timer's DRIVE pin. When ESP was done doing its thing it would signal HIGH to TPL on the DONE pin which made the DRIVE go LOW and disable the MOSFET.

[image]

The issue is that DRIVE would never go HIGH again because ESP's pin stayed HIGH while the device was powered off and would continue to signal on DONE high enough not to let the timer enable DRIVE again. This ghost HIGH signal wasn't full 3.3V but just over 2V, which was still high enough to be interpreted as HIGH.

How can I make sure DONE is not getting a HIGH signal when the board is powered off using a low side switch?

Thank you.

Comment: Are any of the inputs (like the Done pin) being driven high into the ESP while the VIN pin is not providing power? You may be exceeding VDDIO/VSS voltage damaging the chip and "back-feeding" some of the logic...

Comment: Are you completely invested in using a low-side switch? Why?

Comment: @brhans No I'm not, it's just an oddity i ran into and wanted to figure out how get around it if I had to. I'm a software guy dabbling in electronics so alway curious about how and why things work a certain way. For my battery powered project I ended up going with a high-side switch: https://www.edabbles.com/2020/02/20/2ua-deep-sleep-with-esp8266-board-tpl5110-timer/

Comment: Sorry @RonBeyer, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking if TPL ever sets the Done pin to HIGH? It doesn't, it listens on that pin for HIGH signal to disable the DRIVE pin.